# Native Query to Select records to only contain specific ids

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am in the process of implementing an advanced search in my application. I'm sort of new with Oracle and JPA. The database structure has a many-to-many relationship ([ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mDMc.png)) with an intermediate table that contains StudentID and CourseID.

I'm trying to return rows of students that have the list of classes/courses.

Basically, I want the results of

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM STUDENT s
INNER JOIN STUDENT_COURSE sc ON s.StudentID = sc.StudentID
INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.CourseID = sc.CourseID
WHERE ( c.CourseID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CourseID FROM STUDENT_COURSE WHERE CourseID = 'A01') AND c.CourseID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CourseID FROM STUDENT_COURSE WHERE CourseID = 'A02'));
```

which returns the records of students that have both courses 'A01' and 'A02'.

| ID | Age | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 4 | ... | .... |
| 9 | ... | .... |

with courses

| Courses |
| --- |
| A01,A02 |
| A01,A02,A03,X02 |
| A01, A02, A03 |

The goal is to get a similar result using Spring Data JPA. And make it more general to select any number of Course Ids.

I've tried

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM STUDENT s "
+"INNER JOIN STUDENT_COURSE sc ON s.StudentID = sc.StudentID "
+"INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.CourseID = sc.CourseID "
+"WHERE ( s.STUDENTID IN (SELECT DISTINCT STUDENTID FROM STUDENT_COURSE WHERE CourseID =:courseIds)",nativeQuery=true))
public List<Student> advancedSearch(@Param("courseIds") String courseIds);
```

One example, The courseIds field contain "A01,A02". The result would be empty.

I've looked at examples where people use **IN**. When I tried it, it would return records of the student have courses AO1 OR A02 OR Both.

**DON'T WANT THIS**

| ID | Age | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | .... |
| 8 | ... | .... |

With Courses

| CourseID |
| --- |
| A01,A03 |
| A01, X01 |
| A02 |

I want records of students that have both A01 *AND* A02 as shown in the other table.

Comment: The query you posted doesn't appear to return the result you say it does.  There is nothing in the query that aggregates the `courses` into a comma-separated string and the two `in` clauses wouldn't restrict the data you're saying they would restrict.

Comment: I've created a string function which would collect the course numbers from an array field and turn it into a comma-separated string. The result of the query would result in an empty selected result with no records being present.

Comment: Is this "string function" a user-defined aggregate function in Oracle that you want to call in your query?  Or is it a Java function that you call and want the query to return one row per course (your query currently doesn't return any course information at all)?  And your `in` clauses don't make sense-- there is no correlation in them so you're looking to see if any student at all has taken a particular course.

Comment: If you want a query that returns every student that has taken both courses, we can certainly help with that.  It's just very hard to help when the query you're saying is working can't possibly produce the table you say you want or the results you've asked for in the text of the question.

Comment: It's a Java function. Basically, I want the query to return records where the student has taken both courses as per the first table. I want a more general query that can hold multiple courses (A01,A02,...) and return the student records that have taken both these courses instead of one or the other or both like with the in clause

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the query you want is

```
select s.name /* note this column doesn't appear in your ERD */
      ,s.age
      ,s.grade
  from student s
       join student_course sc
         on s.studentID = sc.studentID
 where sc.courseID IN ('A01', 'A02')
 group by s.name /* again, this column isn't in your ERD */
         ,s.age
         ,s.grade
having count(sc.courseID) = 2
```

That doesn't produce the output table you say you want.  But neither does the query you posted.  This will return all the students that have taken both courses (you could add a `distinct` to the `having` clause if the data model were to change to allow a student to take a course multiple times).  It won't give you the list of all courses that student has taken as a comma-separated list.  But the query you posted doesn't return any course information either.

If this isn't what you are looking for, it would be really helpful to update your question with

- The DDL for your schema in text form (so we can run it) rather than as an image
- The DML to insert whatever sample data you want
- The actual results you'd want the query to return (since there is a conflict between what the query you posted returns, the table of data you say you want, and the descriptive text of what you are trying to accomplish, it is confusing to try to figure out which is right).

Comment: You're actually close, it gets the result that is desired. I want to create a JPA query that can get the result of more general parameters, hence the use of `:courseIds` in which it can have a combination of multiple course Ids ([Z01,Z02, A01,A02] or [C01,C04] etc.) and returns the recordsof students that have the combination of course Ids.

Comment: @WattMonki - So you'd need to adjust the set of course IDs and the number of matches you need to return the student.  I'd want to pass in a collection of courses rather than using dynamic SQL to assemble the SQL statement to avoid hard parsing every time.